# React-Formik: How to create registeration form using Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am learning **React.js** and want to use **Formik** for my project. In backend I've created **registration** endpoint, which works fine in frontend as well with simple **form**. I don't know how to implement **Formik** instead of simple **form**. I can't move forward, since all the time i get the same **error**:

```
 Line 121:20:  'firstName' is not defined  no-undef
 Line 122:19:  'lastName' is not defined   no-undef
 Line 123:16:  'email' is not defined      no-undef
 Line 124:19:  'password' is not defined   no-undef
```

How to get rid of that error and make it work?

Here is the **register** component with default form, which works fine.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Register = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const saveRegister = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstName: firstName, 
        lastName: lastName,   
        email: email, 
        password: password,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setData(result)
        console.log(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('error'))
  }

  const handleFirstName = (e) => {
    setFirstName(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleLastName = (e) => {
    setLastName(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleEmail = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value)
  }

  const handlePassword = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    saveRegister()
    setFirstName('')
    setLastName('')
    setEmail('')
    setPassword('')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firsName"
          onChange={handleFirstName}
          value={firstName}
          placeholder="firstName"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          onChange={handleLastName}
          value={lastName}
          placeholder="lastName"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleEmail}
          value={email}
          placeholder="email"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="password"
          onChange={handlePassword}
          value={password}
          placeholder="password"
        />

        <button type="submit">signup</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

In here I'm trying to implement **Formik** instead

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import {
  Formik,
  Form,
  Field,
  ErrorMessage,
} from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'




function Register() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const saveRegister = (values) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstName: values.firstName,
        lastName: values.lastName,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setData(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('error'))
  }
  const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    lastName: '',
    firstName: '',
    password: ''

  }

  const onSubmit = (values, setSubmitting) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    console.log(values);
    saveRegister(values)
    setSubmitting(false)


  }

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    firstName: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    lastName: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email('Invalid email format').required('Required'),
  })

  return (

    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >

      {({ values, isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form >
          <div>
            <label htmlFor='email'>E-mail</label>
            <Field
              type='text'
              id='email'
              name='email'
            />
            <ErrorMessage name='firstName' />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor='firstName'>firstName</label>
            <Field
              type='text'
              id='firstName'
              name='firstName'
            />
            <ErrorMessage name='lastName' />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor='lastName'>lastName</label>
            <Field
              type='text'
              id='lastName'
              name='lastName'
            />
            <ErrorMessage name='lastName' />
          </div>

          <div >
            <label htmlFor='password'>password</label>
            <Field
              type='password'
              id='password'
              name='password'
            />
            <ErrorMessage name='password' />
          </div>

          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>

  )
}

export default Register
```

Comment: there are no firstName, lastName, email and so on into your Register component. Consider pass  them through props for example.

Comment: sorry. i see. maybe try to get them by initialValue.firstName and so on. There are no firstName, lastName, email and password itsel, they are into some object, properties of some object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <>
      <Formik {{ initialValues, validationSchema, onSubmit }}>
      </Formik>
   </>
```

and your on submit method

```
  const onSubmit = (values, setSubmitting) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    console.log(values);
    saveRegister(values)
    setSubmitting(false)
```

and in your saveRegister

```
      const saveRegister = (values) => {
         values.email //and so on
      }
```

Comment: Hey @Олег Войтинський thank you very much for the answer. 
Actually I don't have the errors already , but post  method doesn't work. 
I updated my question, so that you see how I modyfied the code. and I have this warning in devtools
 "Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: setSubmitting is not a function
    at onSubmit (index.js:139)
    at Formik.tsx:885
    at Formik.tsx:1236
    at Formik.tsx:791"

Comment: @Greg in your on Submit method do:
( values, { setSubmitting } ) 
instead of:
( values, setSubmitting )

Comment: @Greg Good luck !
P.S. Also you don't need to put localhost:8000 into your url directly. Read about proxy and how to work with them in React. After reading and configuring proxy delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json and run npm install and then npm run start.